# Dart timeout() does not seem to be triggering after specified duration

Tags: dart, timeout

I'm trying to wrap a function call in a retry and timeout. The retry below seems to be working fine, but the timeout() doesn't seem to be triggering as expected at all.

I've tried setting the ontimeout to print a message, throw an exception, throw a TimeoutException, and in all cases the expected timeout triggered. I've also tried adding a sleep() in the function being called to ensure that it takes longer then the timeout() duration.

```
await retry(
        () => _sendUpdateTaskRequest(resultsJson).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5),
            onTimeout: () => throw new Exception("ERRRR!")),
        retryIf: (Exception e) =>
            e is SocketException ||
            e is TimeoutException ||
            e is ClientException,
        maxAttempts: requestRetryLimit,
      );
```

Comment: 1. By supplying an `onTimeout` callback, `Future.timeout` won't automatically throw a `TimeoutException` if it times out.  If you want a `TimeoutException` to be thrown, omit the callback. 2. I don't think that using `sleep` necessarily ensures that your `Future` will timeout.  If the `Future` computation ends up being completed by some other thread/isolate/process, it can complete anyway.  Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Your description is hard to follow. You say that 1) the retry seems to be working fine, 2) the timeout doesn't seem to be triggering, and 3) in all cases the expected timeout triggered. What I can see from the code, and as @jamesdlin says, you are throwing an `Exception` instance on timeout, but only `retryIf` catching a more specific exception than what you throw, so the *retry* should not happen on timeout with this code.

Comment: This change (https://github.com/yusufm/flutter/commit/dc441f8f072ead572bcbb95b33bb1571cd570b06#diff-def9611b102b0ea9412f7538d5ad03ca44db2e2f61b9b46de7014d119289716dR191) hopefully provides a better picture. If you look at the test on line 191, it has a sleep greater than the timeout, which I would expect to cause the timeout() to trigger, retry to take place, and then on the second call to MockClient, a 500 response to be generated. But it doesn't get to the second call, just gets the 200 response on the first iteration.

Comment: The problem with that example is that `sleep` is blocking. You simply stall your isolate for 5 seconds, then return a value. No timers fire during that time, so the returned value completes the returned future before any timer has a chance to run. When the timeout timer does run, it finds the task already complete and does nothing. Try using `await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));` instead of using `sleep`. That allows other asynchronous operations to run while awaiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lrn's comment was accurate. Changing the `sleep` to await `Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5))` was the correct course of action.